# How to pass an image from one form to another one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to pass a picture from form1 to form2, I get the pic by selecting it on a open file dialog, I would like to make it appear on the second form (form2) after pressing a button

This is the open file dialog:

```cs
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Imagenes|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif";
    ofd.Title = "Profile picture";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
       string urlArchivo = ofd.FileName;
       string nombre = ofd.SafeFileName;

       Userpic.Load(urlArchivo);
       Subirfoto.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (...) {
        //MAKE THE PIC APPEAR ON FORM2
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that winform?

Comment: It is, c#.NET .

Comment: SDEscobedo's answer is all good advice, but I wonder what part of it @MEEXTTv does or does not understand how to achieve.  I suspect there are even more fundamental things about how to create two forms and maintain references to them to be explained.  Once you can access an instance of `Form2` (e.g. `form2`) in a function defined in a `Form1` class the rest is relatively straightforward.  There's no evidence in the original question that this much as been set up.  This question should be modified to show where the references to instances of Form1 and Form2 are currently being stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the path in a public string variable `urlArchivo`, then load the image in a second picturebox located in the `form2` when launching the click event:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (urlArchivo != "") {
         // display image in picture box 
         pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(urlArchivo)
    }
}
```

you can also make the reference directly (so you wouldn't load the image twice):

```cs
pictureBox2.Image = form1.pictureBox1.Image
```

Even better you can define a public property in the forms and get the image from one to another:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //set image of form2 as image of form1
    form2.myImage = form1.myImage
}
```

`myImage` would be defined in each form as `property`. You can see details of defining properties in a form [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/65zdfbdt(v=vs.120)).